# How does getcwd work in Linux?

Tags: linux, api

I make a directory in my urxvt:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/MyDir
```

then

```
$ cd /tmp/MyDir
```

then I run second copy of urxvt and do:

```
$ rm -r /tmp/MyDir/
```

I close the second copy of urxvt and switch to the first copy of urxvt and do:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/MyDir
```

pwd from coreutils v 2.21-2 uses getcwd to get a working directory. How does getcwd get a working directory which is already deleted?

Comment: It was deleted, but it wasn't changed.

Comment: You are floating in space.

Comment: The many-worlds interpretation of Quantum Physics applies here, and Erwin Schrodinger is chuckling (or not) somewhere. Your directory is both alive and dead, and which is seen depends on the observer.

Comment: A directory is a special file which contains a list of pairs: inodeNum <-> fileName
I think when I do  
    $ rm -r /tmp/MyDir  
  
the entry with name MyDir will be removed from the list of /tmp and then getcwd will not find pair inodeNum <-> MyDir in this list.